# Troubleshooting No Sellable Items

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I have created a catalog semi following the Habitat plugin, but using methods to create:

```
await _persistEntityPipeline.Run(new PersistEntityArgument(item), context);
```

The process seems to work correctly. I can see categories, their child categories and sellable items through the commerce business tools. After doing this, I was expecting to see these items on the front end.

I can find them in the database.

I can find them one at a time using PostMan:

```
{{ServiceHost}}/{{ShopsApi}}/SellableItems('ENV_Master,Entity-SellableItem-AA237_318,')?$expand=Components($expand=ChildComponents($expand=ChildComponents($expand=ChildComponents($expand=ChildComponents))))
```

Result:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://localhost:5000/Api/$metadata#SellableItems/$entity",
    "CompositeKey": null,
    "CreatedBy": null,
    "UpdatedBy": null,
    "DateCreated": "2018-09-04T21:06:34.3666257Z",
    "DateUpdated": "2018-09-04T20:24:36.3062164Z",
    "DisplayName": "2018 ICD-10-CM Expert for Physicians: The Complete Code Set",
    "FriendlyId": "AA237_318",
    "Id": "Entity-SellableItem-AA237_318",
    "Version": 3,
    "EntityVersion": 1,
    "Published": true,
    "IsPersisted": false,
    "Name": "AA237",
    "Policies": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Availability.AvailabilityAlwaysPolicy",
            "PolicyId": "b00ba625b47e41069814b1443c5a2bc1",
            "Models": []
        },
        {
            "@odata.type": "#Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Pricing.ListPricingPolicy",
            "PolicyId": "a29bbca4b22b4109a202ddf14ebbd8c7",
            "Models": [],
            "Prices": [
                {
                    "CurrencyCode": "USD",
                    "Amount": 81
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "@odata.type": "#Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Pricing.PurchaseOptionMoneyPolicy",
            "PolicyId": "3bb4e6d567ad4fb58fd41a3b35b92e0b",
            "Models": [],
            "Expires": "2018-09-04T21:11:34.3706496Z",
            "SellPrice": {
                "CurrencyCode": "USD",
                "Amount": 81
            },
            "FixedSellPrice": false
        }
    ],
    "SitecoreId": "de7523d6-283a-49ef-833d-bc241365b750",
    "CatalogToEntityList": null,
    "ParentCatalogList": "b1da3bad-9621-7915-3ce6-a4457204798a",
    "ParentCategoryList": "a6f49394-1a07-25ce-6005-5e1bdfc0c78d",
    "ChildrenCategoryList": null,
    "ChildrenSellableItemList": null,
    "ItemVariations": null,
    "Description": "This essential book for diagnostic coding includes.",
    "ItemTemplate": null,
    "ProductId": "AA237_318",
    "Brand": "",
    "Manufacturer": "",
    "TypeOfGood": "",
    "Tags": [],
    "ListPrice": {
        "CurrencyCode": "USD",
        "Amount": 81
    },
    "Components": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Catalog.DisplayPropertiesComponent",
            "Id": "ac54aeb30ba5443bbb305625d9ddf02e",
            "Name": "",
            "Comments": "",
            "Policies": [],
            "DisambiguatingDescription": "",
            "DisplayOnSite": true,
            "DisplayInProductList": true,
            "Color": "",
            "Size": "",
            "Style": "",
            "ChildComponents": []
        },
        {
            "@odata.type": "#Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Workflow.WorkflowComponent",
            "Id": "7638fb8752bf4788b42d1ab46a5cd2c9",
            "Name": "",
            "Comments": "",
            "Policies": [],
            "Workflow": {
                "Name": "DefaultCommerceWorkflow",
                "EntityTarget": "Entity-Workflow-DefaultCommerceWorkflow",
                "Policies": []
            },
            "CurrentState": "Approved",
            "ChildComponents": []
        },
        {
            "@odata.type": "#Sitecore.Commerce.Core.LocalizedEntityComponent",
            "Id": "d769ba98786a4d0a8ecb9f3fb0af19ab",
            "Name": "",
            "Comments": "",
            "Policies": [],
            "Entity": {
                "Name": "",
                "EntityTarget": "Entity-LocalizationEntity-a339da44dd9d4d03a09c695576e3299a",
                "Policies": []
            },
            "ChildComponents": []
        },
        {
            "@odata.type": "#Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Catalog.CatalogsComponent",
            "Id": "1251ea730990445280bc89fef8bc0fed",
            "Name": "",
            "Comments": "",
            "Policies": [],
            "ChildComponents": [
                {
                    "@odata.type": "#Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Catalog.CatalogComponent",
                    "Id": "bdd3ba9911a84b2eabbb4a6ca1725a0e",
                    "Name": "ENV_Master",
                    "Comments": "",
                    "Policies": [],
                    "CatalogLanguages": [],
                    "DefaultLanguage": null,
                    "ItemDefinition": "",
                    "ChildComponents": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "@odata.type": "#Sitecore.Commerce.Core.MessagesComponent",
            "Id": "598a1e8a15ec4b5a8e49d479545229b7",
            "Name": "",
            "Comments": "",
            "Policies": [],
            "Messages": [
                {
                    "Code": "Pricing",
                    "Text": "ListPrice<=PricingPolicy: Price=$81.00"
                },
                {
                    "Code": "Pricing",
                    "Text": "SellPrice<=ListPrice: Price=$81.00"
                }
            ],
            "ChildComponents": []
        },
        {
            "@odata.type": "#Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Inventory.InventoryComponent",
            "Id": "7464711206624a29890fc2aa293e9c0a",
            "Name": "",
            "Comments": "",
            "Policies": [],
            "InventoryAssociations": [],
            "ChildComponents": []
        }
    ]
}
```

However, I get no items back using PostMan to retrieve all sellable items:

```
{{ServiceHost}}/{{ShopsApi}}/SellableItems
```

Result:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://localhost:5000/Api/$metadata#SellableItems",
    "value": []
}
```

I assume this is the reason why I am not getting any items on the front end, but I cannot figure out why none are returning. How can I go about troubleshooting this?

Note: I have not added any inventory for these items. Is that required to return results?

What about variations? Must there be at least one variant? I would assume no, but I am not sure. I see when creating inventory information it has a parameter of variant Id. I would assume this could be empty.

Is there any kind of checklist of things that must be in place in order to return sellable items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After runnging sellable item all variations on a habitat item versus one that I created, I noticed it was missing the following block:

```
{
            "@odata.type": "#Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.ManagedLists.ListMembershipsComponent",
            "Id": "55c6a9d0c6da4eeb88ace11249a72336",
            "Name": "",
            "Comments": "",
            "Policies": [],
            "Memberships": [
                "SellableItems",
                "CatalogItems"
            ],
            "ChildComponents": []
        }
```

Adding this block of code before running the persist method resolved the issue:

```
var listMembershipComponent = new ListMembershipsComponent();
listMembershipComponent.Memberships.Add("SellableItems");
listMembershipComponent.Memberships.Add("CatalogItems");
item.Components.Add(listMembershipComponent);
```